# Count specific key/value pairs in dynamic json object

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a json object which will contain key-value pairs for clients for example, the clients will vary on a day to day basis, depending on which ones have made a certain transaction on said day of the month. My data will therefore only contain the transactions made by clients. Here is an example of my data object for the first day of the month

```
$scope.dailybreakdown = [
      {'day': '1', 'client':'client1', 'received': '3', 'approved':'0'},
      {'day': '1', 'client':'client2', 'received': '8', 'approved':'1'},
      {'day': '1', 'client':'client3', 'received': '4', 'approved':'0'},
      {'day': '1', 'client':'client4', 'received': '4', 'approved':'0'},
      {'day': '2', 'client':'client1', 'received': '3', 'approved':'1'},
      {'day': '2', 'client':'client4', 'received': '12', 'approved':'5'},
      {'day': '3', 'client':'client1', 'received': '10', 'approved':'2'},
      {'day': '3', 'client':'client3', 'received': '5', 'approved':'1'},
      {'day': '3', 'client':'client8', 'received': '1', 'approved':'0'},
      {'day': '3', 'client':'client9', 'received': '2', 'approved':'2'},
]
```

The data for the second day may contain more or less clients and they could be different, since clients who have not made any transactions will not be present in the object whatsoever. This object would obviously contain data for every day of the month and not just for the first three day as in the sample i added above.

I am using this data to display it graphically in a table and on flot charts on my view. This is all well and good, but where I am looking for some assistance is to how to sort this data and count it.

For instance my table needs to display the total number of transacations for each day. This means I need to count all the Day 1 kay/value pairs and create totals for each field. (total received, approved & recalculate a percentage)

Since this json object could be gigantic, depending on the number of clients thats transacted each day, should I create a new json array in my controller to hold this daily data or is there a way I can filter through it and count/recalculate each day as needed?

My table row looks as follows: (which would also need to change to accomodate the data filtering done in the controller for the client totals)

```
<tr ng-repeat="daily in dailystats" ng-click="setSelected($index);" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}">
                  <td>{{daily.day}}</td>
                  <td>{{daily.received}}</td>
                  <td>{{daily.approved}}</td>
                  <td>{{daily.percentage}}</td>
                </tr>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I have not been working long with json data objects and I have not been successful in finding any resources or examples to help me with this task.
To anyone willing to help, you have my gratitude in advance.

Comment: When you say "_this json object could be gigantic_" why at all do the calculation clientside? It gives a lot more sense to do it serverside and then deliver the calculated result to the client instead.

Comment: You are correct. The problem is that I am still unsure of what the data will look like, I am merely preparing for the worst case scenario. I do agree that the calculations could be done server side, but that part is out of my control and I was curious how to do it on my controller either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a way of going through each row in your json table and using a for loop to find all the days equal to 1, 2, 3...etc then finding the "received" total and adding them all together and pushing that total number to a new array then using ng-repeat displaying that total in a table. I hope this helps you along the right track...

## Index.html

```
   <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Recieved</th>
        <th>Approved</th>
        <th>Percentage</th>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="daily in dailybreakdown" ng-click="setSelected($index);" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}">
                  <td>{{daily.day}}</td>
                  <td>{{daily.received}}</td>
                  <td>{{daily.approved}}</td>
                  <td>{{daily.percentage}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Recieved</th>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="day in days" ng-click="setSelected($index);" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}">
                  <td>Day {{$index + 1}}</td>
                  <td>{{day}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

## app.js

```
  $scope.days = [];

  $scope.dailybreakdown = [
      {'day': '1', 'client':'client1', 'received': '3', 'approved':'0'},
      {'day': '1', 'client':'client2', 'received': '8', 'approved':'1'},
      {'day': '1', 'client':'client3', 'received': '4', 'approved':'0'},
      {'day': '1', 'client':'client4', 'received': '4', 'approved':'0'},
      {'day': '2', 'client':'client1', 'received': '3', 'approved':'1'},
      {'day': '2', 'client':'client4', 'received': '12', 'approved':'5'},
      {'day': '3', 'client':'client1', 'received': '10', 'approved':'2'},
      {'day': '3', 'client':'client3', 'received': '5', 'approved':'1'},
      {'day': '3', 'client':'client8', 'received': '1', 'approved':'0'},
      {'day': '3', 'client':'client9', 'received': '2', 'approved':'2'},
]


for(var x = 1; x <= 31; x++){
   var count = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.dailybreakdown, function(value, key) {

   if(value.day == x){
     count += parseInt(value.received,10);
   }
  });
    $scope.days.push(count);
  console.log($scope.days);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/TK9QPwkcDWSJ1NjbH95a?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much, I checked out the plunkr and seems like this will definitely be a step in the right direction. I had tried using a standard for in my javascript function but you thankfully reminded of the angular foreach. I was also researching the use of underscore to help me get to this solution but it seems yours answer is just as good. I will update once i've implemented and tested. :)